# Calculate proper total in query?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a table like this

```
| customer_id | item_id | price | amount |
```

I want to retrieve the amount of money each customer has spent in a single query.

I have tried:

```
SELECT SUM(price * amount) AS total FROM table GROUP BY customer_id
```

but this spits out astronomically high values for `total`. It cannot be correct.

I also tried

```
SELECT @total := @total + (price * amount) AS total FROM table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @total := 0) CONST
GROUP BY customer_id
```

but this doesn't start from `0` for each customer, so the previous totals will stack up...

How do I properly retrieve the data I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial query is correct:

```
SELECT SUM(price * amount) AS total
FROM table
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

(although I would include `customer_id` in the `SELECT` clause.)

If you have "astronomically high values" then the issue is your data.  Quite possibly, the issue is that "price" is really "total" on each row.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add customer id to your select clause.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the calculation of total.

Comment: The question said "each customer"

Comment: . . The aggregation is specified by the `group by` clause.  The presence of the columns in the `select` clause does not affect the number of rows produced by the query.  I agree that the `customer_id` should be in the `select` clause, but it was not the problem in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be correct. I tried on my server the following:

```
create table test (customer_id int, item_id int, price money, amount int)

insert test values (1,1,10,2)
insert test values (1,2,12,4)

insert test values (2,1,10,2)
insert test values (2,3,5,1)
insert test values (2,4,0.5,21)

SELECT customer_id,sum(price*amount) FROM test
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
select customer_id,sum(price * amount) from table group by customer_id
```